# iText 7 - cell text rotation

Tags: c#, itext7

I am using iText 7 C# to build a pdf.
Here is my issue.. I am trying to add a date to the last row. Since I do not have much space available I am trying to rotate it vertically.. but the text is wrapping to the next line. Also, I wanted the text to be exactly center of cell (vertically and horizontally after the rotation). Can I have the rotation slightly fall to the right like '/'?

```
// add signed date row
table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("")).SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(1 * 5)).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("")).SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(7 * 5)).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
index = 0;
foreach (var month in months)
{
    var dateCell = new Cell().SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(1 * 5))
                            .Add(new Paragraph("3/5/23")).SetFontSize(8);
    dateCell.SetRotationAngle(Math.PI/2);
    table.AddCell(dateCell);
    index++;
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job, including the TextAlignment and preventing of word wrap

```
var dateCell = new Cell().SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(1 * 5))
        .SetHeight(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(30)) // Adjust the cell height as needed
        .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER) // Set text alignment to center
        .SetPaddingBottom(10) // Adjust the bottom padding as needed
        .Add(new Paragraph("3/5/23")).SetFontSize(8);

    // Adjust rotation angle to make it fall slightly to the right
    dateCell.SetRotationAngle(Math.PI / 4);
```

Alternative from comment

```
var paragraph = new Paragraph("3/5/23");

// Adjust rotation angle to make it fall slightly to the right    
paragraph.SetRotationAngle(Math.PI / 4);

var dateCell = new Cell().SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(1 * 5))
        .SetHeight(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(30)) // Adjust the cell height as needed
        .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER) // Set text alignment to center
        .SetPaddingBottom(10) // Adjust the bottom padding as needed
        .Add(paragraph).SetFontSize(8);
```

Comment: If I set the RotationAngle to Paragraph then its working fine.. not to the cell